# igraph clusters from dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, igraph

I'm trying to move a codebase from R to python and I need to move the R function from igraph over from the following:

```
 g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(edges)
 clusters <- igraph::clusters(g)
```

To an equivalent in python, however when I try:

```
edges = pd.DataFrame({"from":[0,1,2,4], "to":[1,2,3,5]})
g = igraph.Graph.DataFrame(edges)
print(g.clusters())
```

I get each of the elements of the graph individually.

[image]

I don't think this is due to the clusters call being the wrong thing because if I do the following:

```
graph = igraph.Graph([(0,1), (1,2), (3,4)])
print(graph.clusters())
```

I get two distinct clusters. I think it must therefore have something to do with the way I'm creating the graph from the dataframe?

[image]

Comment: Do not assume that similarly named functions work the same way in R and Python. Very often, it is not the case. Check whether you are creating a directed or undirected graph.

Comment: I guess this is a seperate question but why does the graph need to be undirected for clustering to work?

Comment: What you are doing is not clustering ("clustering" is a very ambiguous term), but decomposition into connected components. In fact `clusters()` in R has been deprecated for years now and you should use `components()`. Look up what weakly and strongly connected components are to understand.